# How to stop audio changing from monitor to laptop when monitor is off

Tags: audio, hdmi, energy-saving

I have a DELL U2518D and speakers connected to the monitor. The audio uses the HDMI cable. So far so good, but when the monitor goes off (because of the energy saving feature) the audio is disconnected and begins to play in the laptop's speakers.

I'm running Windows 10.

Is there some configuration tweak to keep using the monitor audio even if it's in energy saving, or to stop the playback when the monitor is off?

Comment: Have you used the OSD menu (On-Screen Display): Power Save Audio - On/Off 
Turns the Audio Power on or off during power save mode.

Comment: Maybe you don't have that on your monitor? I have an ST2420L from Dell but that is 2010.

Comment: @vssher I don't have this option in the OSD

Comment: This could help, if you have not tried it: Or, you can right click the Start Button, click on Power Options, click on Change plan settings, and set it to turn off the display after the number of minutes you desire. Make sure that, on the same screen, the Put the computer to sleep delay is long enough to meet your listening needs. Otherwise it will go to sleep after that period of no input activity expires.   https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/how-to-turn-off-display-with-audio-playing-windows/a9d0dadd-1048-4786-9986-ae37a58cd0d9

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: My solution:

- Go to power managment of Windows (Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings)
- and select: "Turn off the display" to Never.
- Then go to "Screen saver settings"
- and select "blank" and click on the item: "On resume, display logon screen" after X minutes you want to.

This will keep your monitor screen "off" and music still playing through your monitor, as also your windows get locked for safety after Xmins.